# How to crowdfund for Solar Nonprofit to garnish funds to initiate first project

Tags: site-growth

I am the founder of a nonprofit organization trying to achieve our first project of installing photovoltaic solar panels in our city's largest public high school energy spender. Garnishing funds is the biggest barrier. We have support of the public school system and engineer and local partners in town. Our job is to gather funding to execute the project.

I am unfamiliar with crowdfunding and creative and effective ways to raise money. Can someone please offer guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Successful crowdfunding​ requires building a community first and getting everyone on board with the same goal and than starting the campagin. For a non profit holding events to find the community needs are over the course of a few months before starting the campagin is an option. You can also reach out to similar groups to see how they did it.

For example http://www.acecoop.ca